# Define custom icon based on key?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have model data which contains several keys for each entry, of interest is `color`.

I would like to specify a custom icon based on the value in `color` but am having troubles getting that value.

This is how my model looks:

```
  { key: "legendVendor", geo: "Vendor", color: vendorColor },
  { key: "legendFactory", geo: "Factory", color: factoryColor },
  { key: "legendVendorFactory", geo: "Vendor Factory", color: vendorFactoryColor },
  { key: "legendSupplier", geo: "Supplier", color: supplierColor },
```

This is how my color constant are defined:

```
  var vendorColor = "#C8DA2B"; 
  var factoryColor = "#800080"; 
  var supplierColor = "#CCD1D1";
  var supplyChainColor = "#FFD700";
  var vendorFactoryColor = "#34c0eb";
```

This is how I am setting the shape based on color:

```
  function geoFunc(geoname, color) {
    var geo = icons[geoname];
    // var color = icons[color];
    if (geo === undefined) geo = icons["cloud"];  // use this for an unknown icon name
    if (typeof geo === "string") {
      geo = icons[geoname] = go.Geometry.parse(geo, true);  // fill each geometry
    }

    switch(color) {
      case vendorColor:
        // code block
        geo = icons["heart"]
        geo = icons[geoname] = go.Geometry.parse(geo, true); 
        break;
      default:
        // code block
    }        

    return geo;
  }
```

And this is how I am calling that function:

```
  myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Auto",
      {isTreeExpanded:false},
      {doubleClick: function(e, node) {node.expandTree(1);}},
      $(go.TextBlock, {text:"Text",width:100,height:100,textAlign:"center",font:"12pt sans-serif",margin:3,wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapDesiredSize,alignment:go.Spot.BottomCenter},new go.Binding("text", "geo")),
      $(go.Shape,
        { margin: 3, fill: colors["white"], strokeWidth: 0 },
        new go.Binding("geometry", "geo", "color", geoFunc), // magic happens here <--------
        new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
```

How can I pass along the value of `color` to the function `geoFunc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting a run-time error because "color" is not a conversion function. It might help to use `go-debug.js` to get more error or warning messages.

If you delete the "geo" argument to the Binding constructor, you will have a valid call to the constructor, and then the `geoFunc` function will be called and passed the value of `data.color`.